# Why does background-color have no effect on this DIV?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="background-color:black" onmouseover="this.bgColor='white'">
    <div style="float:left">hello</div>
    <div style="float:right">world</div>
</div>
```

Why does the background color not show as black? I cannot set the width and float, is it possible without them?

Comment: changed your title to something a bit more informative. Others might have the same problem in the future, so make it easy for them to find your question :)

Comment: I can't figure out what in the *heck* the answers are even going off of in this question.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Since the outer div only contains floated divs, it renders with 0 height. Either give it a height or set its overflow to hidden.

Answer (score 20):

Change it to:

```
<div style="background-color:black; overflow:hidden;" onmouseover="this.bgColor='white'">
<div style="float:left">hello</div>
<div style="float:right">world</div>
</div>
```

Basically the outer div only contains floats. Floats are removed from the normal flow. As such the outer div really contains nothing and thus has no height. It really is black but you just can't see it.

The overflow:hidden property basically makes the outer div enclose the floats. The other way to do this is:

```
<div style="background-color:black" onmouseover="this.bgColor='white'">
<div style="float:left">hello</div>
<div style="float:right">world</div>
<div style="clear:both></div>
</div>
```

Oh and just for completeness, you should really prefer classes to direct CSS styles.

Comment: While lobstrosity's answer is excellent, this is a better solution.You don't have to explicitly declare the height (you may not know it). I also like to use <br style="clear:both" />.

Comment: @cletus and what should we do in case we have dynamic inner divs and we dont have an option to make them float,

Answer (score 0):

Floats don't have a height so the containing div has a height of zero.

```
<div style="background-color:black; overflow:hidden;zoom:1" onmouseover="this.bgColor='white'">
<div style="float:left">hello</div>
<div style="float:right">world</div>
</div>
```

overflow:hidden clears the float for most browsers.

zoom:1 clears the float for IE.

Answer (score 0):

This being a very old question but worth adding that I have just had a similar issue where a background colour on a `footer` element in my case didn't show.  I added a `position: relative` which worked.